# Finding equilibrium of diagonal matrice

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Ok. I am dealing with a diagonal matrice, this one:

$$M=\begin{Bmatrix} 
0.8 & 0 &0\\ 
0 &1.2& 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{Bmatrix}$$
How do I go about finding the Equilibrium. I have tried and got three eigenvectors: (1   0   0)
              (0,  1,  0)
              (0   0   1)
But I am not sure what to do from here. my task say: Find an equilibrium state for the process, i.e. a state $(x_s, y_s, z_s)$ such that:
$M\cdot(x_s, y_s, z_s)=(x_s, y_s, z_s)$
Any suggestions?

Comment: Hint: a non-zero equilibrium state of a matrix is always an eigenvector of the same matrix.  Can you see why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to solve

$$Mx=x$$

We can rewrite $x=Idx$, where $Id$ is the identy matrix.

$$Mx-Idx=0$$
$$(M-Id)x=0$$

$$(M-Id)x=[\begin{Bmatrix} 
0.8 & 0 &0\\ 
0 &1.2& 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{Bmatrix}
-\begin{Bmatrix} 
1 & 0 &0\\ 
0 &1& 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{Bmatrix}]
\begin{Bmatrix} 
x_s\\ 
y_s\\
z_s
\end{Bmatrix}
$$

$$=\begin{Bmatrix} 
-0.2 & 0 &0\\ 
0 &0.2& 0\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{Bmatrix}
\begin{Bmatrix} 
x_s\\ 
y_s\\
z_s
\end{Bmatrix}$$

$$=\begin{Bmatrix} 
-0.2x_s\\ 
0.2y_s\\
0
\end{Bmatrix}=\begin{Bmatrix} 
0\\ 
0\\
0
\end{Bmatrix}$$

Now you can solve for your $x$ vector. As you will see any vector with $(x_s=0,y_s=0,z_s=c)$, where $c\in R$ is an arbitrary constant is an equilibrium (aka fix point) of your matrix.

Comment: You are welcome. But please try to use LaTeX Syntax next time, as it is easier to read and people will more likely respond to your questions.

Comment: @rufaelJ.O And accept the answer by clicking the tick mark if it answers your question! I might also want to upvote it.

Comment: So M is going to be my coeffisient matrix? how do I solve for x, exactly? I am pretty slow on the uptake. sorry

Comment: I edited my answer.

Comment: Really appreciate the time and effort. You have my gratitude. I live in Norway, and our math curriculum is slow compared to like America. That's what i have heard and/or beilive at least.

Comment: No problem, hope to see you again on MSE ... but using LaTeX Syntax :D.

Comment: If you are still here i would love for you to help me out on this one:  The attractor basin for this equilibrium state is given as all states (x, y, z) such that
M^n*(x, y, z)  →(xs, ys, zs) when n → ∞
e) Determine the attractor basin for the equilibrium state (xs, ys, zs) you found in exercise d). d being the one you helped me with

Comment: What exactly do you mean?

Comment: Its ok if the problem is too complicated you have already been to help

Comment: What exactly is a "attractor basin"? Do you mean basis? Your vector for equilibrium is $(0,0,z_s)=z_s\cdot(0,0,1)^T$. Hence, all the equilibrium vectors, can be constructed form the linear combinations of the vector $(0,0,1)^T$One possible basis for your equilibirum is $B = \{(0,0,1)^T\}$.

Comment: yeah lets go with basis, but how did you come to your answer?

Comment: Let us consider a equilibirum vector like $(0,y_s,z_s)^T=y_s(0,1,0)^T+z_s(0,0,1)^T$. Here the basis would be $B = \{(0,1,0)^T,(0,0,1)^T\}$

Comment: So if I had an equilibrium vector of zs*(1, 1, 2) what would the basis be?

Comment: $(1,1,2)^T$. As you only have one parameter $z_s$, you can only have one vector.